# Как в WooCommerce добавить кнопку «Купить в 1 клик» на странице wishlist?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый вечер подскажите пожалуйста как можно добавить кнопку купить в один клик на страницу wishlist? Использую плагин Buy one click WooCommerce а для wishlist YITH WooCommerce Wishlist. Возможно ли реализовать с помощью других плагинов?

Answer (score 1):

думаю это можно сделать через шорткод плагина **Buy one click WooCommerce** и экшн **yith_wcwl_table_product_after_add_to_cart**.

```
add_filter( 'yith_wcwl_table_product_after_add_to_cart', 'add_buy_one_click_button_to_wishlist' );

function add_buy_one_click_button_to_wishlist( $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && function_exists( 'coderun_buy_plugin_init_core' ) ) {
        echo do_shortcode( '[viewBuyButton id=' . $product->get_id() . ']' );
    }
}
```

с помощью этого кода после кнопки добавить в корзину на странице списка желаний будет кнопка купить в один клик, отображаться она будет для простых товаров которые доступны для покупки